# N1QL : Aggregate distinct values from different levels of document into a single array

Tags: arrays, couchbase, sql++

I have documents in format:

```
  {
    "firstName": "Emery",
    "lastName": "Wing", 
    "gender" : "F"
    "userId": "00Z",
    "peers": [
      {
        "peerId": "42F"
      },
      {
        "peerId": "14A"
      }
    ]
  }
,
  {
    "firstName": "Brian",
    "lastName": "Wing",
    "gender" : "M"
    "userId": "42F",
    "peers": [  
      {
        "peerId": "00Z"
      },
      {
        "peerId": "5VH"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kevin",
    "lastName": "Hart",
    "userId": "22N",
    "gender": "M"
  },
```

.......

I want to Select the details of all the Users whose Last Name is 'Wing' along with their Peers. 
As you can see, the 'peers' collection stores the meta ID's of the documents of his peers.

For This I am trying to store userId and PeerId into a single array and then use a join to fetch the information of all of them but can't find a way to do this as both fields are at different levels.

The query I used and the result is as follows:

```
Select ARRAY_AGG([u.userId,u.peers[*].peerId]) as ID        
From user u
Where u.type = 'User' 
and u.lastName = 'Wing'
;
```

I was expecting it to create a single array with all the values on same level but i got the following result instead:

```
    "ID": [
      [
        "00Z",
        [
          "42F",
          "14A"
        ]
      ],
      [
        "42F",
        [
          "00Z",
          "5VH"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

The result I want is all thesse distinct IDs as :

```
"ID": [
      "00Z",
      "42F",
      "14A"
      "5VH"
  ]
```

so that I can apply join and get the details of these distinct IDs.

Please Help..

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd include the code you've tried, and the specific error that results.

Comment: Hi @theMayer, I;ve edited the question. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY_AGG([u.userId,u.peers[*].peerId]),3)) as ID        
From user u
Where u.type = 'User' 
and u.lastName = 'Wing'
;
```

OR

```
SELECT
ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY_INSERT(IFMISSINGORNULL(u.peers[*].peerId,[]),0,u.userId)),2)) AS ID
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.type = 'User' AND u.lastName = 'Wing';
```

Comment: Hi @vsr,  for your first query, following error is showing: 
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "Invalid function ARRAY_FLATTEN. - at )"
}

And for second query, the error message is: 
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at ]"
}

P.S. I am using Couchbase 5.0 to run this query.

Comment: I have modified the query and posted it as the answer. Thanks a lot for your guidence. You saved the day :)

Comment: In ARRAY_INSERT(), the second argument is for the position at which we want to insert and the third argument is the value.

Comment: Thanks pointing it. If you don't know position you can use array_append()

Answer (score 0):

This query is working:

```
Select ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY_INSERT(IFMISSINGORNULL(u.peers[*].peerId,[]),0,u.userId)),1)) As ID
From user u
Where u.type = 'User'
and u.lastName = 'Wing'
```